# My weather app only loads the data on the first try, and I have to refresh the page before it works again

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to figure out this bug for several days and I need some help.

This code is for a weather app that I am building that takes in coordinates after you share your location, or a city name from a search bar. This code only works one time however, meaning you have to refresh the page before you can type in a new location to search up, and if you allow the page to take your location, you won't be able to even search up a new city using the search bar.

````
// This section is for the search bar and submit button
let submit = document.querySelector('.weatherSubmit');
let searchBar = document.querySelector('.inputValue');

searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        submit.click();
    }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchBar.value}&units=imperial&APPID=4edd74c5cec3113209554fa2045fdb73`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        let {lat, lon} = data.coord;

        onecall(lat, lon);
        reverseGeocode(lat, lon);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('Wrong city name!'));
})

// This takes in the data and displays it
const showData = (data) => {
    let current_weather_container = document.querySelector('.current_weather_container'); 
    let {temp, sunrise, sunset, wind_speed, dt, humidity} = data.current;
    let {description} = data.current.weather[0];
    let {max, min} = data.daily[0].temp;
    
    description = description.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + description.slice(1);
    wind_speed = Math.round(wind_speed);
    max = Math.round(max);
    min = Math.round(min);
    temp = Math.round(temp);

    let dateInMillisec = dt * 1000;
    let sunriseInMillisec = sunrise * 1000;
    let sunsetInMilliSec = sunset * 1000;
    let dateObj = new Date(dateInMillisec);
    let sunriseTimeObj = new Date(sunriseInMillisec);
    let sunsetTimeObj = new Date(sunsetInMilliSec);
    let date = dateObj.toLocaleString("en-US", {weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});
    let sunriseTime = sunriseTimeObj.toLocaleString("en-US", {hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"});
    let sunsetTime = sunsetTimeObj.toLocaleString("en-US", {hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"});
    //This is the current weather section
    current_weather_container.innerHTML = 
        `
                <div class='current_time_container'>
                    <div class='current_date'>${date}</div>
                </div>
                <div class='current_weather'>
                    <div id='submitDiv'>
                        <input class='weatherSubmit' type="submit" value="Search">
                        <input class='inputValue' type='text' placeholder="Enter city name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class='weather_class' id='current_temp'>
                        <div class='current_weather_item'>${temp + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='weather_class'>
                        <div id='description' class='current_weather_item extraPadding'>${description}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='current_data'>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'Sunset: ' + sunsetTime}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'Sunrise: ' + sunriseTime}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'Humidity: ' + humidity + '%'}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='current_data'>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'High: ' + max + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'Low: ' + min + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='current_weather_class'>
                            <div class='weather_item'>${'Wind: ' + wind_speed + 'mph'}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
    ;
    //This is the hourly section
    let hourlyForecast = '';
    let counter = 0;
    data.hourly.forEach((hour) => {
        let hourTime = hour.dt;
        hourTimeInMilli = hourTime * 1000;
        hourTimeObj = new Date(hourTimeInMilli);
        time = hourTimeObj.toLocaleString("en-US", {hour: "numeric"});
        while(counter < 12 && hourTime > dt) {
            hourlyForecast +=
                `<div class='forecast_weather_class'>
                    <div class='increaseFont'>${time}</div>
                    <div class='weather_image'><img id='icon2' class='icon2' src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${hour.weather[0].icon}.png"></div>
                    <div class='weather_item alignLeft'>${hour.weather[0].description.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + hour.weather[0].description.slice(1)}</div>
                    <div class='weather_class_container'>
                        <div class='weather_class alignLeft'>
                            <div class='weather_item increaseFont alignLeft'>${Math.round(hour.temp) + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
                return counter++;
        }
    });
    let top = document.querySelector('.top');
    top.innerHTML = hourlyForecast;
    //This is the daily section
    let dailyForecast = '';
    let counter2 = 0;
    data.daily.forEach((day) => {
        let dayTime = day.dt;
        dayInMilli = dayTime * 1000;
        dateObject = new Date(dayInMilli);
        time = dateObject.toLocaleString("en-US", {weekday: "short", day: "2-digit"});
        if (counter2 === 0) {
            return counter2++;
        } else {
            dailyForecast += 
            `<div class='forecast_weather_class alignLeft'>
                <div class='increaseFont'>${time}</div>
                <div class='weather_image'><img id='icon2' class='icon2' src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${day.weather[0].icon}.png"></div>
                <div class='weather_item'>${day.weather[0].description.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.weather[0].description.slice(1)}</div>
                <div class='weather_class_container'>
                    <div class='weather_class alignLeft'>
                        <div class='weather_item increaseTempFont '>${Math.round(day.temp.max) + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                        <div class='weather_item decreaseTempFont '>${Math.round(day.temp.min) + '\u00B0F'}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
        }
    });
    let bottom = document.querySelector('.bottom');
    bottom.innerHTML = dailyForecast;
}
// This adds the name of the city to the page
const nameSpot = (data) => {
    let cityName = document.querySelector('.cityName');
    let {city} = data;
    cityName.innerHTML = `
    <h2 class='cityName'>${city}</h2>
    `
}


/// This grabs the lat & longitude
function grabGeolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((success) => {
        let { latitude, longitude } = success.coords;
        let lat = latitude;
        let lon = longitude;

        onecall(lat, lon);
        reverseGeocode(lat, lon);
    });
}
grabGeolocation();

// This grabs all the data but the city name
function onecall(lat, lon) {
    let weatherApiUrl = fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=imperial&appid=4edd74c5cec3113209554fa2045fdb73`);
    weatherApiUrl.then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        showData(data);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('Unable to grab coordinates!'));
}
// This grabs the city name
function reverseGeocode(lat, lon) {
    let cityGeoLocationUrl = fetch(`https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lon}&localityLanguage=en`);
    cityGeoLocationUrl.then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        nameSpot(data);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('Unable to grab coordinates!'));
}```
````

Comment: your are updating your input elements whe nyou are adding html via js, the old addEventListener dont auto inject into your new html